# How do I change my lock screen in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: unity, 13.10, lock-screen, screensaver, gnome-screensaver

Currently my lock screen is what I am assuming is the default lock screen.
the command: gnome-screensaver-command -l activates this screen.

I installed light-locker and want the system to use this instead, but when my system goes into suspend it still activates the gnome-screensaver's lock screen.

Also, the reason for wanting to switch is the gnome lock screen doesn't always allow me to "Switch User".

Thanks.

Comment: That's funny.. it lets me switch users.

Comment: Supposedly `light-locker-command -l` should make it use light-locker instead of gnome-screensaver. If you want Ctrl+Alt+L to lock it you will have to change the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I installed light-locker and can run light-locker-command -l, but gnome-screensaver is still being used. Interestingly enough, once light-locker was installed, the gnome-screensaver lock screen is allowing me to switch users again. At least for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is handled in gsettings.

I used this command:
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver user-switch-enabled

After this I did a reboot and user switching worked again.